# How does "send to" mean "allow to enter"?

Tags: etymology, verbs, prefix

Ayto doesn't expound the shift from "send to" toward "allow to enter"? I don't understand the "hence".

> #### admit [15]
>
> This is one of a host of words, from
> *mission* to *transmit*, to come down to English
> from Latin *mittere* ‘send’. Its source, *admittere*,
> meant literally **‘send to’, hence ‘allow to enter’**. In the 15th and 16th centuries the form *amit* was
> quite common, borrowed from French *amettre*,
> but learned influence saw to it that the more
> ‘correct’ Latin form prevailed.

*Word Origins* (2005 2e) by John Ayto, p 8 Left column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, "send to" and "allow to enter" are not universally equivalent.
But there are situations where they mean the same, and such weaker similarity seems to be enough when words change meaning over time.

Consider, for example, some kind of a guard (or a bouncer or a doorman or some such person) at a door, controlling who gets in.
When the guard allows someone to enter, they send them to whatever is behind the door.

But the most important thing is not to take prefixes literally.
Prefixed verbs in Latin are much like phrasal verbs in English, and the meaning of the whole need not be the combination of the meanings of the constituents.
While *admittere* is indeed literally "send to", a look [at its dictionary entry in Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=admitto&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) shows that "send to" is not an accurate description of the verb.

Comment: The point about prefixes is well taken. But note also that the unprefixed base word *mittere* can hardly be boiled down to a single meaning of “send” either. [L & S give](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmitto): *to cause to go, let go, send, to send off, despatch, etc.* And that is just the basic meaning.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Indeed! While the basic or original meaning might be "send", it is hardly a good description of the whole verb. And adding a prefix only makes these things worse, so it would be quite the surprise if *admittere* had a clean meaning "send to".